# Pylons - how to use an old project in a new environment?

Tags: python, project, upgrade, pylons

I have an old project, it written under Python 2.5/2.6, Windows.

We had Python 2.6/Win7/x64 now, and I tried to start it. 
I got the old project that running nondebug mode in a server, and 
copied into local folder. 
When I tried to yesterday start it, I got this error:

15:44:58,038 DEBUG [pylons.configuration] Loaded None template engine 
as the default template renderer

I see the google, but they are points to config.init_app, that is does 
not exists.

TOday I reinstalled Python, but with Py2.7, pylons and mako.

But when I tried to stat it, I got only this message: 
07:36:36,377 DEBUG [pylons.configuration] Initializing configuration, 
package: 'x'

And no more information about die... :-(

So what do you meaning, how can I raise this "undead" project to debug 
some things? 
( it was good experience with Python/Pylons, but I'm sad now that I 
not choose PHP previously, because of package changes).

Thanks: 
   dd

Comment: If you're not able to get an answer here, the [pylons-discuss](http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss) group is active and helpful.  (And then you can post their solution here for the benefit of future Stack Overflow users.)

Comment: I also post it to this group, but I don't got answer yet... :-(

Answer (score 1):

might be obvious but did you run "python setup.py develop" on the application package so that the dependencies could be installed?

Comment: My pylons application don't have a package. I have only running environment with py25, old pylons, etc.